# Mocha and Chai with NodeJS, simple server test failing with a 404 (should be 200)

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai, chai-http

I have wrote a simple test using Mocha and Chai. The test is returning as `failed`. After changing to my correct test directory and running `npm test` the error returned is the  below. Please can someone help me figure out why 9000 is already in use?

```
1) Uncaught error outside test suite
  SERVER TESTS
    2) Should list all of the /gets


  0 passing (43ms)
  2 failing

  1) Uncaught error outside test suite:
     Uncaught Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::9000
  2) SERVER TESTS
       Should list all of the /gets:

      Uncaught AssertionError: expected { Object (_events, _eventsCount, ...) } to have status code 200 but got 404
      + expected - actual

      -404
      +200
```

**test.js**

```
// Unit tests for my server using Mocha and Chai

var chai = require("chai");
var chaiHttp = require("chai-http");
var server = require("../hangman-server.js");
var should = chai.should();

chai.use(chaiHttp);


describe("SERVER TESTS", function() {

    it("Should list all of the /gets", function(done) {
        chai.request(server)
        .get("/get")
        .end(function(err, res){
          res.should.have.status(200);
          done();
        });
    });

});
```

**hangman-server.js**

```
// Creating a listener on the specified port
server.listen(port, async function() {
    // Connect to Mongoose.
    await mongoose.connect(uri, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true
    });
    console.log("Connected to DB");

    // Output for terminal, 9000 should display in place of the port
    console.log("Listening on " + port);
})

app.get("/", function(request, response) {
    response.status(200).sendFile("/", {root: "client"});
});
```

**My package.json which includes mocha and chai**

```
{
  "name": "SOFT355-HangMan",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "._hangman-server.js",
  "directories": {
    "test": "test"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.7.9",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "chai-http": "^4.3.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "http": "^0.0.0",
    "mocha": "^6.2.2",
    "mongoose": "^5.7.13",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.2",
    "websocket": "^1.0.30",
    "websocket.io": "^0.2.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha",
    "dev": "nodemon hangman-server.js",
    "start": "node hangman-server.js",
    "server": "nodemon hangman-server.js"
  },
```

Comment: In your `scripts` section of `package.json`, you have `nodemon hangman-server.js`  for `dev` and `server` are you sure that you didn't start any of those before?

Comment: @t.niese Ah, I see do I only need to include one of those, either for the `dev` or `server`

Comment: No that's not my point, I just was wondering if you started one of those two scripts `dev` or `server` with `npm` before you started your test? Because if so then `nodemon` would keep your server alive, and your test would not be able to start another one at port `9000` because there would already be one running.

Comment: @t.niese I see, I was starting my server via my terminal up until last night when I included nodemon within my package.json. So I ensured no server was running at all, then went into Visual Code, and ran `npm start` which started the server. I then opened up another terminal to run the `npm test` which still failed due to this error, should I NOT be starting the server up whilst running tests?

Comment: Yes you should **not** start the server using `npm start`, because in your case the `require("../hangman-server.js");` will start the server. Or you need to remove `require("../hangman-server.js");`, but if you start the server from within your test then you need to wait until the server started before allowing the tests to run.

Comment: I see, thank you @t.niese so whenever I run the `npm test`, never start my server before hand, thank you. Still failing however with a `404`?

Comment: About the `404`, you request `/get` but your server will only respond for `/` because `app.get("/",` will register the middleware for an exact match of `/`.

Comment: GENIUS!!!! Thanking you @t.niese :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for the `Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::9000` error is because of you run `npm start` in one terminal and after that `npm test` in another terminal. So `npm start` starts one server and the `require("../hangman-server.js");` in your test tries to start another server on the same port and that results in this error message.

About the `404`, you request `/get` but your server will only respond for `/` because `app.get("/",` will register the middleware for an exact match of `/`.